# Create slug with id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, slug

I would like to create a slug with the element ID, i have try with:

```
$article->slug = $article->id.'-'.Str::slug($article->name, '-');
```

But instead of returning me:

> 247-Hello-World

It saves me:

> -Hello-World

It's just a post of a new article, Example, if the previous article was ID 246, This article becomes 247-Slug-a-b-c. How do I pick up the ID that this article will have?

Comment: What is `$article->id` contain?

Comment: I think you need to post more code to get help on this.

Comment: It's just a post of a new article, Example, if the previous article was ID 246, This article becomes 247-Slug-a-b-c. How do I pick up the ID that this article will have?

Comment: if it's creating of a new article, then as i know article has no ID yet. you have to save an article to get it's id or get last article ID and increment it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the slug AFTER creating the article.

```
$article->save();
$articleID = $article->id;
$article->slug = $articleID.'-'.Str::slug($article->name, '-');
$article->save();
```

[Reference for getting the id of the model »](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-get-insert-id-from-eloquent-model?page=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, it works without () in $article->id